# ogr2ogr SQLite and json_each, filtering using WHERE does not work

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, json, sqlite

using ogr2ogr I want to process a geojson file that has a JSON field (see minimal file below).

I tried the following command to extract the description corresponding to group a from the JSON field:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
        test_minimal.geojson minimal.geojson \
        -sql "SELECT *, json_extract(value, '$.description') AS description
                FROM layer, json_each(jsonprop)
                WHERE json_extract(value, '$.group')='a'" \
        -dialect sqlite \
```

This seemed to work great at first, but in fact, when an object has multiple entries in the `jsonprop` they all show up (it creates multiple objects due to the joining).
So I figured out the `WHERE` part is not working, I tried this command which should create an empty geojson:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
        test_minimal.geojson minimal.geojson \
        -sql "SELECT *, json_extract(value, '$.description') AS description
                FROM layer, json_each(jsonprop)
                WHERE 1=2" \
        -dialect sqlite \
```

But this still gives every result without filtering... Same for `LIMIT` and others.
So it feels like ogr2ogr is not processing the rest of the command, do anyone knows why?

Here is a minimal file:

```
 {
    "layer" : {
        "type" : "FeatureCollection",
        "crs" : {
            "type" : "name",
            "properties" : {
                "name" : "EPSG:25833"
            }
        },
        "features" : [
            {
                "type" : "Feature",
                "geometry" : {
                    "type" : "Polygon",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        [
                            [ -83202, 6837229 ],
                            [ -63984, 6795019 ],
                            [ -35345, 6827242 ],
                            [ -83202, 6837229 ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "properties" : {
                    "id": 1,
                    "jsonprop" : [
                        {
                            "description" : "Obj1 jsonprop in group a",
                            "group" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                            "description" : "Obj1 jsonprop in group b",
                            "group" : "b"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "type" : "Feature",
                "geometry" : {
                    "type" : "Polygon",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        [
                            [ 3202, 6837229 ],
                            [ 23984, 6795019 ],
                            [ 55345, 6827242 ],
                            [ 3202, 6837229 ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "properties" : {
                    "id": 2,
                    "jsonprop" : [
                        {
                            "description" : "Obj2 jsonprop in group a",
                            "group" : "a"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe GDAL cannot support table valued function like json_each "The json_each(X) and json_tree(X) table-valued functions walk the JSON value provided as their first argument and return one row for each element." I recommend to write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask. Include a link to this question.

Comment: Maybe explore the nested attributes [open options](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#open-options)

Comment: Actually, looks like `FLATTEN_NESTED_ATTRIBUTES` doesn't work with doubly nested attributes, i.e a list containing a dict like your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I created an issue on GDAL github:
[https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7464](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed and there is a workaround:

You can workaround the issue by adding extra parenthesis around json_each, that is

```sh
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
        test_minimal.geojson minimal.geojson \
        -sql "SELECT *, json_extract(value, '$.description') AS description
                FROM layer, (json_each(jsonprop))
                WHERE 1=2" \
        -dialect sqlite
```

I hope it helps, thanks again.